# dynamic or static urls?

Tags: url, dynamic, static, seo

does anyone know which is better for SEO rankings? Dynamic or Static?

example:

`http://www.blah.com/this_page.php?id=1234` ( half dynamic cause of the id that changes but everything else stays )

versus

```
http://www.blah.com/totally_dynamic_changing_all_the_time.php
```

Comment: I believe most search engines are aware of query strings, but I don't know that for sure.

Comment: those are both technically "query strings" so both?

Comment: I think on SO it should be required that if you give a "-1" you should have to state why :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is more SEO-friendly, given you make it relevant to the content of the page, not some SHA-1 hash. Your best bet is using the page title, with-no-punctuation-and-spaces-replaced-with-dashes.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with ayanami, I would add that which style would you use:

http://www.blah.com/totally_dynamic_changing_all_the_time.php

http://www.blah.com/totally_dynamic_changing_all_the_time.html

http://www.blah.com/totally_dynamic_changing_all_the_time/

http://www.blah.com/totally_dynamic_changing_all_the_time

is mostly irrelevant from SEO perspective. they are all better than `this_page.php?id=1234` (if the match page content / title)